# How to create a table in databricks from an existing table on SQL

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks, delta-lake

Can someone let me know how to create a table in Azure Databricks from a table that exists on Azure sql server? (assuming Databricks already has a jdbc connection to the sql server).

For example, the following will create a table if it doesn't exist from a location in my datalake.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS newDB.MyTable USING delta LOCATION
'/mnt/dblake/BASE/Public/Adventureworks/delta/SalesLT.Product/'
```

I would like do the same but with the table existing on SQL Server?

Comment: I'm assuming I haven't phrased this question in a format that can be clearly understood as I'm sure this question is common question. Therefore, please let me know if you need further clarification

Comment: do you mean Databricks delta table? if you already have a connection to Sql server, you can simply use `spark.sql("select * from table1")` which will return as Spark DataFrame, then you can transform the dataframe and store it on multiple formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the basic solution for creation of an external table over an Azure SQL table
You can take the url (connection string) from the Azure Portal

```
create table if not exists mydb.mytable
using jdbc
options (url = 'jdbc:sqlserver://mysqlserver.database.windows.net:1433;database=mydb;user=myuser;password=mypassword;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;', dbtable = 'dbo.mytable')
```

Check the following links for additional options

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-table-datasource.html
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html